# What is the value of ip and xp boosts?

Tags: league-of-legends

How much ip do you get in the ip boosts? Is it the same amount for the wins vs days ones? I want to see if the ip and xp boosts are worth getting. I already figured xp is not, because the time spent leveling is valuable!

Comment: i hope I was able to answer your question and give you a little more knowledge than you asked for

Comment: Yes you were! Thank you so much. :) I think the next time I have a completely free day, I will try it out for sure! I don't play extremely often so I never have much ip, and I definitely think this will help based on your answer. :) thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It depends.  At a certain point, day IP boosts will become worth it.  Let's do a little quick math.  For simplicity, I will assume you get 100 bonus IP for the IP bonus.  Some games are more, some are less, but my experience is that it averages out to ~100.

A 6300 IP champ is 975 RP, making each RP spent ~= 6.46 IP.

4 win IP boost  is 290 RP.  1 RP ~= 1.38 IP.
10 win IP boost is 670 RP.  1 RP ~= 1.49 IP.

So you can rule those out.  Even with 1 hour long games and 200 IP bonuses (rarely happens), you're still not even close.  Now it gets a little more tricky.  Number of games that you get the bonus for in a day boost are only limited by the 24 hours in the day.  I'll assume 10 games played each day, and each lasting ~ 30 minutes for ~100 IP bonus per game (About 6-7 hours of gaming when you get the IP boost).

1 day  is  290 RP.  1 RP ~= 3.49
3 day  is  520 RP.  1 RP ~= 5.77
14 day is 1846 RP.  1 RP ~= 7.58

Finally we have something that is worth more.  Now, if you play for 24 hours straight, at ~30 minutes a game, ~6 minutes between end of last game and start of next game, and we assume you do everything outside of the game inside those 4 minutes (bathroom, eating, smoking, w/e)..  that's 40 games in 1 day at an average of 100 IP per game:  1 RP ~= 13.8 IP.  Now it's way better.

Personally I buy the 3 day boost when I know I have 3 days where I can game 15-20 games a day comfortably.  I know I don't have the time for 2 weeks straight of 10 games a day, and I don't usually go on 24 hr binge-gaming sessions.  If you don't have time for 10+ games a day, you're better off using your RP for buying the expensive champs, and using the IP you get in game for runes or cheaper champs.

Answer (score 1):

The IP boost are well worth it I've bought a lot of them and with the boost you range from 150 IP to about 270 per a game.

To break it down for you you get experience for waiting for the game to start normally 10-25 then you get you game IP and that is based on how long the game lasted and how well you did this is normally 50 or 57 to a little over 100 and the boost duplicates what ever you received so if you got 87 for a game you won and 20 for waiting and connecting to the game your boost total would be 107. I recommend buying a 1 day boost and play as much as you can as long as you play 10 games or more its well worth it.

Comment: Just to chime in on the length one.. On a weekend when I know I am going to be doing a bit of solid LoL playing, an IP boost may be worth the time as it effectively doubles your IP boost.. I can not speak to XP though as I have been level 30 way too long.

Comment: the XP boost is not really worth it in my opinion I've only bought one and did not feel I got my moneys worth

Answer (score 0):

The IP boost is more worthwhile than xp boost.  XP boost will give you extra experience which means you will reach summoner level 30 sooner, however this will happen eventually no matter what as long as you continue to play the game.  IP is needed to buy runes and also can get you champions to unlock.  As Riot has a policy of releasing new champions every 2-4 weeks, it helps to have more IP.

The bonus you get from the boost is the same regardless of per win or day boost.  The amount of the bonus depends on how long the game is and whether you won or lost.  It is not affected by the win of the day bonus you get for IP.  They do stack so if you buy both per win and day boost, you will have double bonus IP.

Comment: I did not know they stacked like that, that's really cool thank you

Answer (score 0):

If money isnt an issue it totally depends on how much your play.  If you plan on playing non stop for 3 days, get the 3 day ip boost. If you plan on only playing 1 day then only get the one day boost.  However, if you are a more casual gamer and you have sports or school or w/e, get the wins.  Because if you only play 3 games in a week and u play a simple bot game, you still get more ip even though ip from bot games aren't much. (I reccomend not to waste ip boosts on bot games) And after these 3 games, you will still have 7 left.  So in my opinion it depends on how much you play.